# Shorten If Statement

Tags: java, if-statement, refactoring

Hi I am wondering if there's a way to make the following less redundant. Where 'ones', 'twos', 'threes', etc. are instance variables. (The switch statement doesn't allow them to be case arguments).

```
private int methodX(){

   int consec=0;

    if(ones==1){
        consec++;
    }
    if(twos==1){
        consec++;
    }
    if(threes==1){ 
        consec++;
    }
    if(fours==1){
        consec++;
    }
    if(fives==1){
        consec++;
    }
    if(sixes==1){
        consec++;
    }
    if(consec>=4){
        return 30;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
private int ones;
private int twos;
private int threes;
private int fours;
private int fives;
private int sixes;
```

Comment: If possible, try using a single array instead of many variables and you can use a loop for that.

Comment: I can't belief that I cant find a builtin `boolean -> {0,1}` function in Java...

Answer (score 1):

A good trick for such cases would be to write a function instead of the ifs.

Not a big gain, but you get some clarity in the code.

Example

```
   void incrementIfEqual(int what, int value)
   {
        if (what==value)
             consecs++;
   }
```

then you can have

```
   {
      incrementIfEqual(ones,1);
      incrementIfEqual(twos,1);
      ...
      incrementIfEqual(sixes,1);
   }
```

It's a nice rule of thumb to know : if you can copy paste, you can make a function.

Comment: Small addition for op: by the same rule, the integers should be in an array.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're rolling two dices of six faces, and trying to count consecutive rolls of equal faces.
you can try to input the faces and see whether they're the same or not.

```
private boolean Same(int i, int j){
return (a==b);
}
```

and then you call it every time when you need to compare.

```
if(Same(i,j))consec++;
```

or there is even a simpler way:

```
if(i==j)consec++;
```

if you don't need to check it in other places.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your instance variables with a Map or List or an array and then process it in a loop:

```
for (String key : counts){
    if (counts.get(key) == 1
       consec++ 
}
```

Comment: You're comparing Strings with "==", I suggest an edit.

Comment: @runDOSrun Where does he compare Strings? Neither `1` is a String nor `counts.get(key)` is necessarily a String.

Comment: But this code is strange anyway. I wonder what `counts` supposed to be. It has to be `Iterable` and its `#get` method is needs to return a second type. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to check your code again. Do you really want to use several if or an if-else? switch statement does exactly what an if-else statement would do.

Comment: Well, can you provide an example for his case?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to infer consecutive rolls this way, a simpler approach is to check this as your roll the numbers and you won't need any of this code.

Let say you want to check if when you roll 4 dice you get 4 different rolls.

```
Random rand = new Random();
long uniqueRolls = IntStream.range(0, 4)
                             .map(i -> rand.nextInt(6) + 1)
                             .distinct().count();
if (uniqueRolls == 4)
   System.out.println("They were all different");
```

I suspect that want ever calls you method could be changed so you don't need the method at all.